# connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: php, nginx, php-7.2

I have a question about nginx. I have some webservers on my environment using nginx  and they are behind Load balancer. Suddenly, all web services are down and I found this error log on nginx:

> [error] 7097#7097: *44471950 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: *.web.com, request: "HEAD /3.1?language=id&app=ios HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "web01.com"

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 6):

Please check Below Value, Default must be 128.

```
sysctl net.core.somaxconn
```

Increase this value by running the following command.

```
echo "net.core.somaxconn=65536" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
```

Then restart PHP-FPM to take effect of new changes (Depends on Version of PHP-FPM).

```
service php-fpm restart 
service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Comment: I know it's old but, it would be nice if you could write the reason to increase the value.

Comment: @IamGhale, he is trying to increase the maximum number of socket connections. [Here](https://serverfault.com/a/1029488) is explained fully. Cheers!